# RoR: Devise 500 error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm getting a 500 error when I go to /users/sign_in (or any other devise page).

This is all the log says:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 67.161.236.149 at Mon Jun 13 02:51:47 +0000 2011
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):




Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 67.161.236.149 at Mon Jun 13 10:40:25 +0000 2011
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 135ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x605f360>):
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users'):
```

Have you run `db:migrate` since creating your User model?

Also,

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x605f360>)
```

suggests that you don't have a root path configured.  This is something in routes.rb that matches requests to www.yourdomain.com/.  You could use something like

```
root :to => "pages#home"
```

which would direct any request to www.yourdomain.com/ to the home action of the pages controller.

Comment: I've run db:migrate, yes.  There is a database called 'users'...so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: I figured out the problem!  My httpd.conf file was setting up the virtual host to only listen to port 80. I removed the :80 on my VirtualHosts and voila!